# How to save dictionaries of different lengths to the same table in database?

Tags: python, dictionary

What would be the most elegant way to save multiple dictionaries - most of them following the same structure, but some having more/less keys - to the same SQL database table?

The steps I can think of are the following:

1. Determine which dictionary has the most keys and then create a table which follows the dictionary's keys order.
2. Sort every dictionary to match this column order.
3. Insert each dictionary's values into the table. Do not insert anything (possible?) if for a particular table column no key exists in the dictionary.

Some draft code I have:

```
man1dict = {
    'name':'bartek',
    'surname': 'wroblewski',
    'age':32,
    }

man2dict = {
    'name':'bartek',
    'surname': 'wroblewski',
    'city':'wroclaw',
    'age':32,
    }

with sqlite3.connect('man.db') as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    #create table - how do I create it automatically from man2dict (the longer one) dicionary, also assigning the data type?
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS People(name TEXT, surname TEXT, city TEXT, age INT)')

    #show table
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM People')
    print(cursor.fetchall())

    #insert into table - this will give 'no such table' error if dict does not follow table column order
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO People VALUES('+str(man1dict.values())+')', conn)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easiest to save the dict as pickle and then unpickle it later. ie

```
import pickle, sqlite3

# SAVING
my_pickle = pickle.dumps({"name": "Bob", "age": 24})
conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE test (dict BLOB)")
conn.commit()
c.execute("insert into test values (?)", (my_pickle,))
conn.commit()

# RETRIEVING
b = [n[0] for n in c.execute("select dict from test")]
dicts = []
for d in b:
    dicts.append(pickle.loads(d))
print(dicts)
```

This outputs

```
[{"name": "Bob", "age": 24}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NoSQL` databases such as `MongoDB` for this purpose. They will handle these themselves. Using relational data for something that is not relational, this is an anti-pattern. This will break your code, degrade your application's scalability and when you want to change the table structure, it will more cumbersome to do so.

Comment: Thanks Seenivasan. What do you think of sticking with SQL and using SQLAlchemy + SQLite to map dictionary values to database table rows? Will that work in a situation when some dictionaries have more/less keys than the others?

Comment: In that case. You should handle all the needed wrapper code. Define structure(what are the possible keys that may come, data types). Make a table. For every object in your current data, create a table row with data as per the defined structure and fill with none if there is no such key in the current object and then insert it directly into your code.

Comment: Thanks, I thought SQLAlchemy would be smart enough to do that automatically (for example, Pandas concatenation of differently structured dataframes  does that)